# Configure MQTT Broker for iOS

Tags: mqtt, home-automation

I am working on a home automation application for iOS.
For home automation I want to use MQTT along with Quel. But I am unable to figure it out how I install and configure MQTT Broker/Server. Also how do I create topics or get list of all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest place to start is probably with the Mosquitto broker, there are pre-built binaries for most platform available on the download page:

http://mosquitto.org/download/

As for topics, you don't configure them on the broker, they are created on the fly as clients publish or subscribe to them. The only configuration you may want to look at is setting up ACLs for specific topic trees to control which clients can subscribe/publish to.

You don't normally need a list of connected clients, but if you need them look at the admin topics that are kept under $SYS/broker/clients/# sub tree

Comment: I want to use MQTT for home automation. My Client says he has purchased Quel Device for automation. How MQTT Broker will be installed in Quel ? My Main Point is how home automation will be done through MQTTCLient,MQTTBroker,Quel,Z-wave Supported Devices. Could you  please explain more on this ?

Comment: I have installed mosquitto on my mac but how do I connect iOS Client to local host? I'm using this sample app https://github.com/jmesnil/MQTTExample

Comment: One thing I want to know that How Can we configure all devices (Light,Camera,Thermostat) to this Quel(http://www.currentcost.com) and How we can install MQTT Broker on this.

Comment: One last query is How do we get list of all connected devices and their current state through MQTT Broker ?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the Quel bit first time round. If I remember correctly, the Quel is a Android device, so you'll probably have to build a broker specifically for it, and wrap it up as an android app/service to get it started. It may be easier to start with one of the OpenSource pure Java brokers than one written in C (e.g http://code.google.com/p/moquette-mqtt/). As I said earlier, you don't normally need a list of connected clients, so you will need to layer this into your data/topic structure and use things like the LWT to signal disconnects.

Comment: As for the devices, you'll have to work out how to bridge them from their own protocols to a shared MQTT data/topic set.

Comment: @user3563703 I am looking for your email address to discuss this topic.
This is my Skype id - imrahulvyas
This is my gmail address - imrahulvyas@gmail.com